# new BitmapImage from Imagelist.images

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to change the source of windows.media.imagesource

I store all my images in a windows.forms.imagelist

my code is: Source = New BitmapImage((MyImageList.Images(2)))

a system.uri is expected but I cannot find the conversion method

Answer (score 0):

ok i dont know the rest of your code but i asume that for adding the images to the image list you first look for an uri, save the uri's in an Array and then call them from there.
Note:there is no method for getting an Uri from a Bitmap.

Comment: Actually no, i dont use a uri to add to fill the image list. The images are added at design time for conveinience, so they are embedded. It would work if the imagelist source could be converted to a string.